# $E[\exp(-sX)\exp(-sY)]$ for two identically distributed, but correlated random variables X and Y.

Tags: statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation, laplace-transform, correlation

I am trying to figure out the following problem. I am trying to evaluate the expectation: $E[\exp(-sX)\exp(-sY)]$, where $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, but correlated random variables, hence, they are NOT independent. I have access to the Laplace transform of the distribution (i.e., $E[\exp(-sX)]$) but not the exact PDF. I know that it is possible to take the inverse Laplace transform to get the PDF, but it might not be necessary due to the structure of the problem. I can also calculate the correlation coefficient $\rho(X,Y)$ from numerical data. So far I have done the following:
$E[\exp(-sX)\exp(-sY)]=\\E_X[E_{Y|X}[\exp(-sX)\exp(-sY)]]=\\E_X[\exp(-sX)E_{Y|X}[\exp(-sY)]].$

Is there a simplification I am not seeing, or a way to incorporate the correlation coefficient and the known Laplace transforms $E[\exp(-sX)]$ and $E[\exp(-sY)]$.

Edit: What about the following approach: $Cov(A,B)=E[AB]-E[A]E[B]$, where $A=\exp(-sX)$, and $B=\exp(-sY)$. Therefore, $E[A]=\mathcal{L}_X(s)$ and $E[B]=\mathcal{L}_Y(s)$. Then, we calculate $Cov(A,B)$ from numerical data (simulations) and we have:
$E[\exp(-sX)\exp(-sY)]=\mathcal{L}_X(s)\mathcal{L}_Y(s)+Cov(A,B)$

Comment: You cannot express this in terms of the Laplace transforms of $X$ and $Y$ and the correlation coefficient, in general.

Comment: Since you are working with correlations, are $X$ and $Y$ Gaussians? If they are then this problem is relatively simple. Otherwise, as geetha290krm said, you will need more information.

Comment: @forgottenarrow Ok let us assume we can approximate the pdfs of X and Y by a Gaussian distribution and the mean and second moment can be obtained from the Laplace transform that we have. Would that make it possible to incorporate the correlation coefficient?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $(X,Y)$ is a 2-dimensional multivariate Gaussian with respective means $\mu_X,\mu_Y$, variances $\sigma^2_X,\sigma^2_Y$ and covariance $\rho_{XY}$. Note that I'm using the covariance rather than correlation just because it is simpler. Then $(X,Y) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Sigma})$, where
$$\mathbf{\mu} =\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_X\\
\mu_Y
\end{bmatrix} \text{ and } \mathbf{\Sigma} = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2_X & \rho_{XY}\\
\rho_{XY} & \sigma^2_Y
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then the moment generating function $M_{XY}:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ of $(X,Y)$ is known to be given by:
$$M_{XY}(\mathbf{t}) = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\mathbf{t}\cdot (X,Y)^T}\right] = \exp\left(\mathbf{\mu}\cdot\mathbf{t} + \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{t}\right).$$
So,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(-sX)\exp(-sY)\right] = M_{XY}(-s,-s) = \exp\left(-s\mu_X + \frac{s^2}{2}\sigma^2_X\right)\exp\left(-s\mu_Y + \frac{s^2}{2}\sigma^2_Y\right)\exp\left(s^2\rho_{XY}\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp(-sX)\right]\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(-sY)\right]\exp(s^2\rho_{XY}).$$

Now let's assume that $X$ and $Y$ are only approximately Gaussian. Then when is this approximation appropriate? Let me first present a standard result for MGFs:

If the MGFs $M_{X'_n,Y'_n}(t)$ $(X'_n,Y'_n)$ are uniformly bounded for $|t| < |(-s,-s)|+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and if $(X'_n,Y'_n)$ converge weakly to $(X',Y')$ then
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(-sX'_n-sY'_n)\right] = M_{X'_n,Y'_n}(-s) \to M_{X'Y'}(-s) = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp(-sX'-sY')\right].$$

How can we apply this? You said that you should be able to compute $\mathbb{E}[\exp(-sX)]$ for different values of $s$ and $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed. Then by Holder's inequality,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(-sX)\exp(-sY)\right]\leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[\exp(-2sX)]\mathbb{E}[\exp(-2sY)]} = \mathbb{E}[\exp(-2sX)].$$
So if $\mathbb{E}[\exp(-2s'X)]$ is not large compared to the Gaussian approximation of the MGF derived above when $s'$ is as close or closer to the origin than $(-s,-s)$, you can assume your MGF is well-behaved. Then the approximation will be about as good as your pair $(X,Y)$ is close to being Gaussian.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the useful insight! I edited the post with a general approach without needing to approximate the PDFs. What do you think of it?

Comment: Oh yeah, that would work.

Comment: I suppose the problem is that $Cov(A,B)$ is dependent on $s$. So if I have a table of X and Y data, then $Cov(A,B)$ is different for different $s$ values but I do not have a function relating $Cov(A,B)$ and $Cov(X,Y). In your approach, the expression $e^{s^2 \rho}$ is that function but for Gaussian approximation.

Comment: To be precise, in the Gaussian case, $\text{Cov}(A,B) = E[\exp(-sX)]^2(\exp(s^2\rho_{XY}) - 1)$. You could approximate $\text{Cov}(A,B)$ for different values of $s$, but the number of data points you would need to simulate would depend on exactly what you need to do with the Laplacian. Do you need the Laplacian for a specific value of $s$ or are you looking for more detailed information about the function?

Comment: No I want this expression to be a function of $s$, not for a specific one. because in my case, $s$ is actually a random variable with known distribution which I would want to take the average over.

Comment: Can't you just use a direct Monte-Carlo approximation then? You essentially want to compute the expectation, 

$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(-SX-SY)],$$

where $S$ is independent of $(X,Y)$ and follows the distribution of $s$'s that you want to average over.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151674/discussion-between-forgottenarrow-and-secretkeeper).